Efficient listing of ASMs
Famously, the alternating sign matrix theorem gives a product formula for the number $a(n)$ of ASMs of size $n$.  There are multiple proofs of this formula, all somewhat involved.  My question is about a closely related but weaker problem:
Question:
Is there a polynomial time algorithm which inputs an ASM $M$ of size $n$ and outputs an integer $k\in \{1,\ldots,a(n)\}$, such that the map $M\to k$ is bijective?
Note that the algorithm can use the product formula for the number of ASMs or any of its many variations and generalizations, so I am not asking for a new proof.
Example:
To emphasize the difference, note that there is a simple polynomial time algorithm which takes a partition $\lambda$ of $n$ and outputs an integer $k\in \{1,\ldots,p(n)\}$. Namely, precompute all integers $p(n,m)$ of the numbers of partitions of $n$ with largest part $m$.
This is easy to do using formulas $p(n,m) = p(n-m,1) + \ldots + p(n-m,m)$.
Depending on $\lambda_1\in \{1,2,\ldots\}$, split the interval intro smaller intervals $\{1,\ldots,p(n,1)\}$, $\{p(n,1)+1,\ldots,p(n,1)+p(n,2)\}$, etc.  Proceed recursively.
Note: One can show that such algorithm exists for the MacMahon box formula but the construction is somewhat technical, at least the one I found.

You might be interested in the talk Greg Kuperberg gave at Jim Propp's 64th birthday conference: https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/JIM/abstracts.html#Kuperberg. He is interested in developing a framework for expressing ideas like "there can be no bijective proof that the number of order n ASMs is the same as order n TSSCPPs."

I wonder whether this has been investigated in the literature on the complexity theory of the six vertex model, since ASMs are a special case.

Unsure if relevant for the question, but at the OEIS A005130 page there are two links to bijective proofs: Ilse Fischer and Matjaz Konvalinka, A bijective proof of the ASM theorem, Part I: the operator formula, Markus Fulmek, A statistics-respecting bijection between permutation matrices and descending plane partitions without special parts. See also Bijective proofs of alternating sign matrix theorems.

@FabiusWiesner -- I studied these papers before and the answer is: they  are relevant but not helpful.  A bijective proof in [FK] of A=B via AC=BC does not give an efficient listing as in the question (Fulmek's paper is about something else).  Thanks anyway.

@SamHopkins I think Greg is underestimating the power of bijections as combinatorial algorithms.  In particular, I think (hope) the answer to the question I asked is Yes.

@GjergjiZaimi I found the paper Complexity Classification Of The Six-Vertex Model
by Jin-Yi Cai, Zhiguo Fu, Mingji Xia hard to understand, but I think they are saying that the special case of the six-vertex model relevant for ASM enumeration is $#P$-hard (since all six "values" are nonzero, where I think the values should be the weights of the vertices, i.e. all $1$). Of course the special case one needs for this problem, where the relevant graphs are certain subsets of a square and the boundary conditions on the boundary of the square are restricted, might be easier.
